# How to debug after starting without debugging?

Tags: c#, debugging

Using Visual Studio, is it possible to display debugging diagnostic messages like

```
Debug.WriteLine("this is debugger");
```

by first "starting without debugging" and then attaching to process? it seems that doing so will not show any debugging info in output window? I don't know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: Google works wonders when used properly `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can can use `Debugger.Launch` (on a system with an appropriate debugger installed), which will give you a prompt that provides the opportunity to attach an instance of a debugger:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

Comment: is it possible if program has finished execution?

Comment: @user3723486 No, if the process has ended you can't attach a debugger. I mean what is there to debug when the program is no longer running?

Comment: sorry me, I meant when the control has passed the `Debug` statement. and right before its end.

Comment: @user3723486 why don't you do more than just show one line of code so that others can understand what it is you're trying to do.. come on now

Comment: @user3723486 I'm not sure I understand what you mean here. What is the `Debug` statement? Could you give us a broader overview of what you're trying to do? From your title I was under the impression you wanted to attach a debugger after "starting without debugging".

Comment: @MethodMan what I'm trying to find out is whether the debug messages are stripped out after pressing CTRL + F5 and attaching the debugger? as simple as that,

Comment: @user3723486 Which debug messages? When you log a debug message, it doesn't go anywhere if there's no debugger attached to the process. Once you attach the instance of Visual Studio, your debug messages will show up in that instance. You can test all of this yourself.

Comment: @user3723486 Does that actually solve your problem or are you just accepting the answer out of frustration (don't do that).